# Create a view that displays node count?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-modules

Having trouble in views creating what seems like a very simple query.  Display the number (count) of nodes of a given type.  I'm not finding the option in any obvious place...

How to?

Comment: Did you want to show like: "Node type", "Count of nodes of this type" columns?

Comment: yes.  I'm seeing a way to do it now, though display is not great, using args > node-type > summary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [Views Group By](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_groupby) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> This module enriches Views2 functionality with SQL Grouping and Aggregation capabilities.
>
> Ever wanted to design a view that displays top terms for a specific node type and number of nodes for each top term? You could not build such query before, but now you can.
>
> A new field group: SQL Aggregation is added, in Views, once you install the module. The field group has one available field: SQL Aggregation: Group By Fields. The field allows to configure many aspects of "group by" SQL clause and "count()" fields.
>
> Currently only SQL COUNT() function is available due to a limitation in Views2 API. We are working on a Views2 patch to overcome the limitation. Patch will be submitted to Views2 project and, hopefully, applied shortly thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of views it is better to use light custom SQL-query, something like this http://drupal.org/node/105375#comment-1095529